Scraping the first table from a website using BeautifulSoup
I am trying to scrape the first table which is the ten countries with biggest biggest market capitalization table I have written the code but the table is not printed it is giving me out that is not correct this is the code:
'''
# Code for ETL operations on Country-GDP data
# Importing the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url="https://web.archive.org/web/20230908091635/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks"

# Function to extract data using read_html
def extract(url):
    ''' This function aims to extract the required
    information from the website and save it to a data frame. The
    function returns the data frame for further processing. '''
    response = requests.get(url).text
       
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    df = pd.DataFrame(soup)
    tables = soup.find_all('tbody')
    rows = tables[0].find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        col = row.find_all('td')    
            
    return df

# Call the function and print the DataFrame
df = extract(url)
print(df)

'''
this is the output it is giving me:
'''
0
0                                               html
1                                                 \n
2  [\n, [[], \n, [], \n, [window.RufflePlayer=win...
3  \n     FILE ARCHIVED ON 09:16:35 Sep 08, 2023 ...
4                                                 \n
5  \nplayback timings (ms):\n  captures_list: 0.9...
'''

You are setting, or trying to set, the dataframe to the value of the soup response which is the HTML DOM tree. And the lines between df = pd.DataFrame(soup) and return df do not affect the content of the dataframe.

In this particular case, you can simply use pd.read_html and it will be the second table retrieved, so use: pd.read_html(url)[1]. You can also extract the links if you want; check the linked docs.

Pandas read_html is quite flexible and parse all tables of a document (from URL, HTML of filename).
So in your case it is sufficient to provide the url, it will load the full page and extract all tables:
import pandas as pd

url = "https://web.archive.org/web/20230908091635/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks"

It appears that there is an artifact table before the first Wikipedia table, hence the 1 index:
frame = pd.read_html(url)[1]

That's it, this one-liner does directly the job:
   Rank                                Bank name  Market cap (US$ billion)
0     1                           JPMorgan Chase                    432.92
1     2                          Bank of America                    231.52
2     3  Industrial and Commercial Bank of China                    194.56
3     4               Agricultural Bank of China                    160.68
4     5                                HDFC Bank                    157.91
5     6                              Wells Fargo                    155.87
6     7                        HSBC Holdings PLC                    148.90
7     8                           Morgan Stanley                    140.83
8     9                  China Construction Bank                    139.82
9    10                            Bank of China                    136.81

